# Statistical analyses for air and noise pollution relationship

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, pattern-recognition, independence

When air and noise pollution originating from traffic (shared) sources are considered, what statistical analyses (except correlation coefficient) you would recommend/suggest to study whether there exists any relation between their modelled values or not (in an urban environment)?

Googling this question would also return me a lot of options but my aim is to gather recommendations/suggestions for relevant statistical methods/techniques.